# Python:Error in extracting data from input file(xml file),Loop stops after some iterations

Tags: python, python-itertools, extract

I have an XML file which looks something like this,[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aka1r.jpg)
The file contains 5000 profiles(set of data) each containing 92 rows and 5 columns, each profile is separated by 2 lines(which I want to skip).
I want to extract some selected profiles and write to another file.I have made the following program to do this.
But with this code, I'm able to extract only limited profiles.

```
    with open('file.xml') as f:
      for j in lat :
        l=94*j
        i=l-92
        g.write('%s' % j)
        g.write(":-profile")
        g.write("\n")
        for lines in itertools.islice(f, i, l): 
          g.write('%s' % lines)
        g.write("</Matrix>")
        g.write("\n")
        g.write('<Matrix nrows="92" ncols="5">')
        g.write("\n")
```

When I printed 'j',It is taking up all the values of 'lat'(my selected profiles).
In my output file I'm getting values only up to few profiles and after which it simply shows the last lines

```
        g.write("</Matrix>")
        g.write("\n")
        g.write('<Matrix nrows="92" ncols="5">')
        g.write("\n")
```

I know it's very silly,But I'm a beginner in python programming..Please help

I tried printing 'j' and'lines' together, after certain iterations the output showed only the values of j ,there was not output for lines

Comment: Could you show the values of `j` (ie output of `print(j)`)?

Comment: It goes something like this,:- 6
8
10
11
24
25
27
28
36
42
44
54
56
59
60
62
65
67
68
69
80
81
90
92
93
94
96
102
103
105
109
111
113
115
116...... 4939
4941
4943
4945
4947
4950
4953
4954
4955
4957
4958
4960
4961
4962
4964
4972
4974
4978
4979
4980
4982
4987
4989
4991
4993
4996 There are  2037 values in total

Comment: Everything seems to be ok. Without minimal repeatable code and data it is quite difficult to suggest anything. You said `each profile is separated by 2 lines`, I do not see how the code checks these 2 lines.

Comment: I will try to explain, Each profile starts with 2 lines of HTML code followed my 92 rows so totally 94 lines will be there for 1 profile. On the first iteration,j takes the value 6, the code will read between lines 564(94*6) and 472(564-92)  so that is what the logic I applied.Is there any mistake in that?? Thankyou

Comment: If it is not a problem for you, you can temporary upload your sources to github, then I can find where is the problem and fix it for you.

Comment: Ya, I have uploaded the details to GitHub, Thankyou

Comment: I see, but check urls for downloading the files - it is impossible to download them

Comment: I have rectified it.Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

nums_profiles = set()
with open("lat_sel.dat", "r") as num_profiles_file:
    for line in num_profiles_file.readlines():
        for i in line.split():
            nums_profiles.add(int(i))

with open('extracted_output.xml', 'w') as output_file, open('chevallierl91_clear_q.xml', "r") as matrix_file:
    profile_counter = 0

    for line in matrix_file.readlines():

        # save the ending xml tags
        for end_tag in ['</Array>', '</arts>']:
            if end_tag in line:
                output_file.write(line)

        # counting profiles
        if 'Matrix nrows' in line:
            profile_counter += 1

        # save header of xml file
        if profile_counter == 0:
            if '<Array type="Matrix" nelem=' in line:
                line = re.sub('nelem="[0-9]+"', 'nelem="%s"', line) % len(nums_profiles)

            output_file.write(line)

        # check if profile is the one which we need. If so, save data
        if profile_counter in nums_profiles:
            output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: @caty, I would appreciate if you accept the answer :)